# Retriving parent attribute of every child in XML with xpathSApply

Tags: r, xml-parsing, xpathsapply

I'm trying to retrive two vectors of same length, one with attributes of childs, and second with attributes of corresponding parents. Example file:

```
countries.xml <- "<country>
              <city id='1'>
                <place id='1.1'> xxx </place>
                <place id='1.2'> xxx </place>
                <place id='1.3'> xxx </place>
              </city>
              <city id='2'>
                <place id='2.1'> xxx </place>
                <place id='2.2'> xxx </place>
                <place id='2.3'> xxx </place>
              </city>
           </country>"
```

My code so far

```
library("XML")
doc = xmlTreeParse(countries.xml, useInternalNodes = T)
xpathSApply(doc, path = "//city/place/@id")
xpathSApply(doc, path = "//city/place/parent::*/@id")
```

I was hoping to end up with such vectors (named)

```
"1.1" "1.2" "1.3" "2.1" "2.2" "2.3"
"1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2"
```

but instead the second path produces

```
"1" "2"
```

I cound get what I wanted with a loop

```
library(glue)
place_id <- unname(xpathSApply(doc, path = "//city/place/@id"))
city_id <- vector()
for(i in place_id){
  city_id <- c(city_id,unname(xpathSApply(doc, path = glue("//city/place[@id={i}]/parent::*/@id"))))
}
city_id
"1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2"
```

but it is very inefficient and takes ages with large xml.file I'm dealing with. I'm sure there is a way to get what I need with right path in `xpathSApply` but couldn't find it, so could please someone enlight me :)?

**UPDATE** 
@Wietze314 solution works great on my simple example, but i can't adapt it to more complicated xml file. I did manage to change his code to deal with below example

```
countries.xml <- "<continent>
          <country id='c1'>
          <city id='1'>
            <place id='1.1'> xxx </place>
            <place id='1.2'> xxx </place>
            <place id='1.3'> xxx </place>
          </city>
          <city id='2'>
            <place id='2.1'> xxx </place>
            <place id='2.2'> xxx </place>
            <place id='2.3'> xxx </place>
          </city>
       </country>
       <country id=c2'>
          <city id='1'>
            <place id='1.1'> xxx </place>
            <place id='1.2'> xxx </place>
            <place id='1.3'> xxx </place>
          </city>
          <city id='2'>
            <place id='2.1'> xxx </place>
            <place id='2.2'> xxx </place>
            <place id='2.3'> xxx </place>
          </city>
       </country>
        </continent>"
```

this code

```
    pmap_df(list(
  xml_children(cntry) %>% map(xml_children) %>% 
    map(xml_attr,'id') %>% unlist() %>% as.list() %>%
    map(~as_tibble(.) %>% select(city = value)),
    xml_children(cntry) %>% xml_children() %>% map(xml_children) %>% 
    map(xml_attr,'id') %>%
    map(~as_tibble(.) %>% select(place = value))),cbind)
```

returns this

```
    city place
1     1   1.1
2     1   1.2
3     1   1.3
4     2   2.1
5     2   2.2
6     2   2.3
7     3   3.1
8     3   3.2
9     3   3.3
10    4   4.1
11    4   4.2
12    4   4.3
```

but the same code applied to file of my interest fails :( any suggestion?

```
pfile <- http://nextbike.net/maps/nextbike-official.xml",
                  useInternalNodes = T)
pmap_df(list(
  xml_children(pfile) %>% map(xml_children) %>% 
    map(xml_attr,'uid') %>% unlist() %>% as.list() %>%
    map(~as_tibble(.) %>% select(city = value)),
  xml_children(pfile) %>% xml_children() %>% map(xml_children) %>% 
    map(xml_attr,'uid') %>%
    map(~as_tibble(.) %>% select(place = value))),cbind) 

Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
      arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `tidyverse` and `xml2`

```
require(xml2)
require(tidyverse)

cntry <- read_xml(countries.xml)


pmap_df(list(
  xml_children(cntry) %>% map(xml_attr,'id') %>% 
    map(~as_tibble(.) %>% select(country = value)),
  xml_children(cntry) %>% map(xml_children) %>% 
    map(xml_attr,'id') %>% 
    map(~as_tibble(.) %>% select(place = value))
  ),cbind)
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried to get this to work with more than 2 levels, but did not succeed. This is what I have come up so far:

```
require(xml2)
require(tidyverse)

parsedxml <- read_xml(countries.xml)

get_ids <- function(xml){
  xml %>% xml_attr('id') %>% 
    map(~as_tibble(.))
}

country <- parsedxml %>% xml_children() %>% map(get_ids)
city <- parsedxml %>% xml_children() %>% map(~xml_children(.) %>% map(get_ids))
place <- parsedxml %>% xml_children() %>% map(~xml_children(.) %>% map(~xml_children(.) %>% map(get_ids)))

rbind(country[[1]],rbind(city[[1]][[1]],place[[1]][[1]])) %>% apply(1,unlist)
```

result for one city

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] 
value "c1" "1"  "1.1"
value "c1" "1"  "1.2"
value "c1" "1"  "1.3"
```

this ugly code brings it all together:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(1:2,function(x) 
  lapply(1:2,function(y) 
    rbind(country[[x]],rbind(city[[x]][[y]],place[[x]][[y]])) %>% apply(1,unlist)) %>% do.call(rbind,.)))
```

Hopefully someone else has a better solution for this last part.

Comment: It works perfectly with my simplified example, but I'm too stupid to adopt it to files with more levels of nodes. Could you show me how to expand your code, so that it creates 3 variable dataframe from 4-node level xml file, which i included in updated question.